# Are Products of Arc Connected Spaces Arc Connected, or vice versa?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Do Arc-Connected spaces behave well with respect to products? That is, does the following hold -

> $\prod X_\alpha$ is arc connected iff $X_\alpha$ is arc connected $\forall \alpha$, where $X_\alpha$ is non-empty $\forall \alpha$

If not, can we construct a counterexample? I've tried looking for this in various textbooks, but I've not been able to find anything either supporting or contradicting the above claim.

Comment: Is $[0,1]^I$  arc-connected for any index set? I think so (it's even convex) and this implies the reverse direction.

Comment: (Trivial) Counterexample: $\{0,1\} \times \varnothing$. Like for lots of topological properties, to deduce anything about the factors you must demand the product nonempty.

Comment: My bad. Is there one for non-empty spaces.

Comment: Hi there; what's your definition of arc-connected?

Comment: $X$ is arc-connected if for any $x,y \in X$, there exists a homeomorphism $f:I\to X$ such that $f(0) = x$, $f(1) =  y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let all $X_\alpha$ be arc-connected and consider $X=\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ and $x \neq y$ in $X$. Define $$A' = \{\alpha \in A: x_ \alpha \neq y_ \alpha\} \neq \emptyset$$
and for each $\alpha \in A'$ we pick a homeomorphism $h_ \alpha: [0,1] \to Z_ \alpha$ such that $h(0)= x_ \alpha$ and $h(1) = y_\alpha$ by arc-connectedness (and AC). Then $h_{A'} = \prod_{\alpha \in A'} h_ \alpha : [0,1]^{A'} \to \prod_{\alpha \in A'} X_\alpha$ is also a homeomorphism (a Cartesian product of homeomorphisms is easily seen to be a homeomomorphism too) and we clearly have a "homeomorphic path" $p:[0,1] \to [0,1]^{A’}$ defined by $p(t)_\alpha = t$ for all $\alpha \in A'$ that connects the $0$ to $1$ in that subproduct. (basically we are using the convexity of powers of $[0,1]$). Now define $h: [0,1] \to X$ by $\pi_\alpha(h(t)) = h_\alpha(t)$ when $\alpha \in A'$ and $\pi_\alpha(h(t)) = x_\alpha = y_\alpha$ for other $\alpha$. Then $h$ is a homeomorpic embedding of $[0,1]$ into $X$ sending $0$ to $x$ and $1$ to $y$.

The reverse is probably true but not so clear to me yet, a possible start:
Suppose that $X=\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ is arc-connected.
Pick a fixed point $q:=(q)_\alpha$ in $X$ (otherwise $X$ is empty and we cannot show anything interesting).

Fix $\alpha_0 \in A$, and let $x \neq y$ be points of $X_{\alpha_0}$. Define $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ in $X$ by extending them by $q$: e.g. for $\hat{x}$: $\hat{x}_\alpha = x$ if $\alpha = \alpha_0$ and $\hat{x}_\alpha = q_\alpha$ otherwise. Then there is a homeomorphism $h$ from $[0,1]$ into $X$ such that $h(0)=\hat{x}$ and $h(1)=\hat{y}$. I would *like* to conclude that $\pi_\alpha \circ h$ would be a homeomorphic embedding of $[0,1]$ from $x$ to $y$ but even a two-dimensional picture convinces me that this does not need to hold. So we'd have the "morph" $h$ into shape. I don't see as yet how, but maybe others do.

Comment: How exactly did you go from $h_{A'}$ to $p$? You mentioned using 'convexity of powers of $[0,1]$', but I didn't understand what that meant, and so how it affects the problem.

Comment: @IshanDeo Just use the formula I gave as the arc $h$. The rest serves as motivation. $\Bbb R^I$ is a real vector space and the cube is convex in it, so has arcs between all of its points, so here between $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$.

Comment: I apologise for pestering you, but I don't get one more thing - how is $h$ a homeomorphism? I've been able to show it's continuous, but homeomorphic eludes me.

Comment: @IshanDeo It's essentially $h_{A'}$, which is a homeomorphism, composed with the path $p$ which also defines a homeomorphism, plus a constant on the other coordinates which are not touched by $h_{A'}$. So it's clearly injective and it's defined on a compact set and its image is that of $h_{A'}$ essentially (which is already known to be homeomorphic to Hausdorff) so we have a homeomorphism.

Comment: @IshanDeo Why make it so hard on yourself? Assume all spaces are Hausdorff and the distinction path-connected vs arc-connected goes away! Among non-Hausdorff spaces you'll be unlikely to find arc-connected spaces anyway, except trivial ones.

Comment: @kaba better now?

Comment: Further discussion on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368658/arc-connectedness-of-product-spaces) provides a counter-example for the converse.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, this is wrong. There is no arc from, for example, (0,0) to (1,0). What I thought was an arc is a 1-1 path, continuous but not a homeomorphism.

<s>The other implication does not hold. Let $S$ be the Sierpinski space ($\{0,1\}$ with $\{0\}$ the only non-trivial open set) and let $Y$ be an arc-connected space with at least two points. $S \times Y$ is arc-connected but $S$ is not.</s>

Comment: If you take $Y$ to be a point then $S\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $S$ so it's not arc-connected

Comment: How exactly do you show that $S\times Y$ is arc-connected? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Alex Mathers You're quite right. I've modified the answer.

Comment: @Ishan Deo $S \times Y$ consists of two copies of $Y$, only one open in the whole space. Suppose f and g are arcs in the open and closed copies respectively. Define h(t) as f(t/2) for t < 1/2 and g((t+1)/2) for t>= 1/2. Since $S$ has so few open sets, this is still continuous and actually an arc.

Comment: With $h$, are you joining an arc from $0\times a$ to $0\times b$ with an arc from $1\times b$ to $1\times c$?

Comment: @ishan Deo That works if a < b <c but  I was being a bit more general than that,joining an arc from (0,a) to (0,b) - but not including (0,b) - to one from (1,c) to (1,d). Unfortunately that is a 1-1 continuous path but not a homeomorphism. It fails if the intervals (a,b) and (c,d) overlap by more than one point, and to get from (0,0) to (1,0) an overlap is essential.